# Long list of exactly solvable nonlinear SDEs

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, stochastic-differential-equations

In P. E. Kloeden & E. Platen (1995). Numerical Solution of Stochastic Differential Equations.
pg.118, they go over some special cases of nonlinear SDEs $dX_t=\alpha(t,X_t)\,dt+\sigma(t,X_t)\,dB_t$ that have exact solutions.

I am just wondering if there are any more large lists somewhere that you came across. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A follow-up of Kloeden and Platen is C.H. Skiadas, [Exact Solutions of Stochastic Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11009-009-9145-3) (2010).